# Using of possessive_english stemmer in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following analysis settings:

```
"settings" : { 
  "index" : { 
    "creation_date" : "1469213620697",
    "analysis" : { 
      "filter" : { 
        "stem_possessive_filter" : { 
          "name" : "possessive_english",
          "type" : "stemmer"
        }   
      },  
      "analyzer" : { 
        "stem_analyzer" : { 
          "filter" : [ "standard", "lowercase", "stem_possessive_filter" ],
          "tokenizer" : "standard"
        }   
      }   
    },  
    "number_of_shards" : "5",
    "number_of_replicas" : "1",
    "uuid" : "VQgaaZquQUOqKNYxGPH7cg",
    "version" : { 
      "created" : "2020199"
    }   
  }
},
```

Every field of string type has the following mapping:

```
"field_name" : {
   "type" : "string",
    "analyzer" : "stem_analyzer",
    "search_analyzer" : "standard"
 }
```

I want to be able to write ***dementia in alzheimer*** or ***dementia in alzheimer's*** phrase. And as a result, I want to get ***Dementia in Alzheimer's ...***.

[Multi match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) doesn't work if the possession is not used:

`{'query': {'multi_match': {'query': "dementia in alzheimer", 'type': 'phrase', 'fields': ['_all']}}}`

But it works if the possession is used:

`{'query': {'multi_match': {'query': "dementia in alzheimer's", 'type': 'phrase', 'fields': ['_all']}}}`

On the other hand, [Bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) works if the possession is not used:

`{'query': {'bool': {'must': [{'match_phrase': {'Diagnosis': "dementia in alzheimer"}}]}}}`

But it doesn't work if the possession is used:

`{'query': {'bool': {'must': [{'match_phrase': {'Diagnosis': "dementia in alzheimer's"}}]}}}`

How to make all the queries above work?

**-- UPDATE --**

The bool query works if you add `stem_analyzer` in the query. Thus you use it during search. And I get results for a phrase both with and without possession.
`mybody = {'query': {'bool': {'must': [{'match_phrase': {'Diagnosis': {'query': "dementia in alzheimer's", 'analyzer': 'stem_analyzer'}}}]}}}`

But, the multi match query stops working at all if you add analyzer. I don't get any results for a phrase both with and without possession.
`{'query': {'multi_match': {'query': "dementia in alzheimer's", 'type': 'phrase', 'analyzer': 'stem_analyzer', 'fields': ['_all']}}}`

Why the analyzer doesn't work for the multi match query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `phrase` type doesn't work with stem analyzer for the multi match query. But `phrase_prefix` type works. Frankly speaking, I don't know why. There is no hint about it in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#analyzer).

So, the following two multi match queries return the same results for me:

`{'query': {'multi_match': {'query': "dementia in alzheimer", 'type': 'phrase_prefix', 'analyzer': 'stem_analyzer', 'fields': ['_all']}}}`

`{'query': {'multi_match': {'query': "dementia in alzheimer's", 'type': 'phrase_prefix', 'analyzer': 'stem_analyzer', 'fields': ['_all']}}}`

In the boolean query, `match_phrase` works with stem analyzer.
The following two queries return the same results:

`{'query': {'bool': {'must': [{'match_phrase': {'Diagnosis': {'query': "dementia in alzheimer", 'analyzer': 'stem_analyzer'}}}]}}}`

`{'query': {'bool': {'must': [{'match_phrase': {'Diagnosis': {'query': "dementia in alzheimer's", 'analyzer': 'stem_analyzer'}}}]}}}`