# Elasticsearch possessive_english stemmer query returns no hits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I was able to find this other question: [Using of possessive_english stemmer in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38615486/using-of-possessive-english-stemmer-in-elasticsearch?r=SearchResults&s=1|76.2244)
but its been 3 years since there was any activity on it

I am trying to get elasticsearch to ignore ' when indexing and searching. For example:

```
POST my_index/_doc/
{
  "message" : "Mike's bike"
}
```

I want to be able to search for this document using "mikes", "mike's", "mike". I looked and thought that `possessive_english` should accomplish this task but I have been unable to get the expected results.

I created the index with

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "rebuilt_standard": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase", "my_stemmer"      
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_stemmer":{
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "possessive_english"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tested the analyzer with

```
POST /my_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "rebuilt_standard",
  "text": "Mike's bike"
}
```

And this is the result

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "mike",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "bike",
      "start_offset" : 7,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Looks like the analyzer is working. Then I inserted the document with:

```
POST my_index/_doc/
{
  "message" : "Mike's bike"
}
```

When searching for it, it returned 0 results

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {"message": "mike"}
    }
}
GET /my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {"message": "mikes"}
    }
}
```

but

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {"message": "mike's"}
    }
}
```

returned results

It seems like I am missing the configuration on the mapping side of things from the linked question but I am not sure how to set it.

I tested the above with kibana but I am actually using rails and gems 'elasticsearch-model', 'elasticsearch-rails',  'elasticsearch-persistence' with the repository pattern. I am also new to rails so I don't know if its my configs with rails, or elasticsearch, or both that needs work.

I'll post them just in case

```
  include Elasticsearch::Persistence::Repository
  include Elasticsearch::Persistence::Repository::DSL

  client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(url: 'http://localhost:9200', log: true)

  settings index: {
      number_of_shards: 1,
      analysis: {
          analyzer: {
              custom: {
                  type: "custom",
                  tokenizer: "standard",
                  filter: [
                      "lowercase",
                      "english_possessive_stemmer",
                  ]
              }
          },
          filter: {
              english_possessive_stemmer: {
                  type: "stemmer",
                  language: "possessive_english",
              }
          }
      }
  }
  mappings {
    indexes :icon, index: false
    indexes :properties, type: 'nested' do
      indexes :values
    end
    indexes :name
  }
```

in the controller

```
repository = Repository.new
repository.create_index!(force: true)
repository.save(json)
results = repository.search(query: { match: { name: 'Mikes' } })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your analyzer is working fine. I think you have not applied it to your mapping

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "rebuilt_standard": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase", "my_stemmer","english_stemmer"      
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_stemmer":{
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "possessive_english"
        },
         "english_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "english" 
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "message":{
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "rebuilt_standard" ---> pass the analyzer
      }
    }
  }
}
```

possessive_english filter only removes "'" , you cannot use it to search for mikes (it will work for mike though). You will need to use stemmer which reduces words to their base form.

I have an excellent article [here](https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-algorithmic-stemming-tutorial) for further reference.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I was able to get kibana to search for "mike", "mike's" and "mikes" however. Is that not supposed to happen? Also, I must have missed the elasticsearch docs where it mentioned adding it into the mappings. I didn't really see it anywhere until the linked question and thought it should have just worked. Is there a global setting so that I don't have to set it for all fields where I want this to work?

Comment: Default analyzer is the standard analyzer(breaks words in token based on special characters , space etc). If you want to make custom analyzer as default you need to rename it as default ex.PUT my_index_test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase", "my_stemmer"      
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_stemmer":{
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "possessive_english"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}